Measurable sets of reals with sum $\mathbb R$
Let $E$ be a measurable subset of $\mathbb R$ and assume $E+E=\mathbb R$. Does there exist $x \in \mathbb R$ such that $$\{(a, b) \in E^2 \mid a+b=x\}$$ is uncountable, or at least infinite?
I can prove this is true when $E$ has positive Lebesgue measure but I don't know if this is true in the case of null sets.

This doesn't directly answer your question, but this reminds me of the result of Keleti that there exists a subset $E\subset\mathbb R$ of the reals with Hausdorff dimension $1$ which intersects each of its translates (besides $E$ itself) in at most one point. This is equivalent to $$#{(a,b)\in E^2\mid a+b=x}\leq2$$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$.

Ah, I forgot to link it. Here's the paper.

I'm not certain, but this might be dependent on deep axiomatic claims ie if there are cardinalities between countable and continuum. Its giving me those vibes, but i'm not recalling any specific result

@user24142 That would be very interesting if true! I'm interested in any reference for these kinds of things then.

@CarlSchildkraut Thanks, I was aware of that paper.

For each $E\subset\mathbb R$ and $x\in \mathbb R$ put $E_x=\{(a, b) \in E\times E: a+b=x\}$.
There exists a set $E'\subset \mathbb R$ of measure $0$ such that $|E'_x|=\frak c$ for each $x\in\mathbb R$. For instance, let $E''$ be the set of $x\in [0,1)$ that have an $4$ary expansion without $3$'s and $E'=E''+\mathbb Z$.
Proposition. If $E'\subset \mathbb R$ such that $|E'_x|=\frak c$ for each $x\in\mathbb R$ then there exists a set $E\subset E'$ such that $1\le |E_x|\le 2$ for each $x\in\mathbb R$.
Proof. Let $E''$ be the set of $x\in [0,1)$ that have an $4$ary expansion without $3$'s and $E'=E''+\mathbb Z$. It is easy to check that $E'$ has measure $0$ and $|E'_x|=\frak c$ for each real $x$.
Let $\{x_\alpha:\alpha\in\frak c\}$ be the enumeration of the set $\mathbb R$.
By induction for each $\alpha<\frak c$ put $E_\alpha=\{a_\beta,b_\beta:\beta<\alpha\}$.
If $x_\alpha\in E_\alpha+E_\alpha$ then put $a_\alpha=a_0$ and $b_\alpha=b_0$ otherwise
pick $a_\alpha,b_\alpha\in\mathbb E'$ missing the set $$(E_\alpha-E_\alpha+E_\alpha)\cup (x_\alpha+E_\alpha-E_\alpha)/2 \cup (E_\alpha+E_\alpha)/2\cup (x_\alpha+E_\alpha)/3$$
of size less than $\frak c$ such that $a_\alpha+b_\alpha=x_\alpha$. Finally, put $E=\bigcup_{\alpha<\frak c} E_\alpha$.
We claim that $|E_x|\le 2$ for each $x\in\mathbb R$. Indeed,
suppose for a contradiction that $x=a+b=a'+b'$ for some $a,b,a',b'\in E$ such that $a'\ne a$ and $a'\ne b$. Pick the smallest ordinal $\alpha$ such that $\{a,b,a',b'\}\subset E_\alpha\cup \{a_\alpha,b_\alpha\}$.
Up to the renaming of $a$, $b$, $a'$, $b'$ and $a_\alpha$, $b_\alpha$, the following cases are possible.

$a=a_\alpha$, $b,a',b'\in E_\alpha$. Then $a\in E_\alpha-E_\alpha+E_\alpha$, a contradiction.

$a=a_\alpha$, $b=b_\alpha$, $a',b'\in E_\alpha$. Then $x=a_\alpha+b_\alpha=x_\alpha$. On the other hand,
$x=a'+b'\in E_\alpha+E_\alpha$, so $a_\alpha=a_0$, $b_\alpha=b_0$, so $a_\alpha,b_\alpha\in E_\alpha$, which contradicts the minimality of $\alpha$.

$a=a_\alpha$, $b'=b_\alpha$, $a',b\in E_\alpha$. Then
$$2a_\alpha=a_\alpha+b_\alpha+a_\alpha-b_\alpha=x_\alpha+a'-b\in x_\alpha+E_\alpha-E_\alpha,$$
a contradiction.

$a=b=a_\alpha$, $a',b'\in E_\alpha$. Then $2a_\alpha=a'+b'\in E_\alpha+E_\alpha,$ a contradiction.

$a=a_\alpha$, $a'=b'=b_\alpha$, $b\in E_\alpha$. Then
$$3b_\alpha=a_\alpha+b+b_\alpha=x_\alpha+b\in x_\alpha+E_\alpha,$$
a contradiction. $\square$



Thanks, I didn't think of doing this construction inside a nullset! Now I'm wondering if this could be done in $\mathsf{ZF}+\mathsf{DC}$, but I highly doubt it.
